# How can I sort the positioning of this HTML Table? - I need the Submit button on the right hand side and need to remove the spacing on the left

Tags: html, css

I’m just putting together a HTML table for a wix site and for some reason the table is coming out looking all kinds of funky. There seems to be excessive spacing on the left hand side and the submit button will not position to the right edge of the input boxes? Also, I am trying to change the background colour of the input boxes to '#3A3B3F' but for some reason everything I try is not working, not sure if I have made a fundamental error in the code somewhere. If anyone can provide me with any assistance to this I would be eternally grateful! this is a copy of the tables code and a screengrab of how the table currently looks: [Screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dfKm.png)

```
<style>
    #crmWebToEntityForm tr , #crmWebToEntityForm td { 
        padding:6px;
        border-spacing:0px;
        border-width:0px;
        }
</style>
<table style='width:600px;background-color:#3A3B3F;background-color:#3A3B3F;color:#3A3B3F'><tr>
<td  colspan='2' align='left' style='color:#ffffff;font-family:Avenir;font:Avenir;font-size:18px;word-break: break-word;'><strong></strong></td>
</tr> <br></br>
  <tr><td  style='word-break: break-word;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font- 
family:Avenir;font:Avenir;width:30%;'><span style='color:red;'></span></td>
  <td style='width:40;' style='height:40px'' ><input type='text' placeholder="First Name" 
style='width:200%; height:50' box-sizing:border-box;'  maxlength='0' name='First Name' /> 
   </td>
    <td style='width:350px; style='height="50px" ></td></tr>
    <tr><td  style='word-break: break-word;text-align:;font-size:16px;font- 
 family:Avenir;font:Avenir;width:350px'><span style='color:red;'></span></td>
 <td style='width:40%;' ><input type='text' placeholder="Last Name" style='width:200%; 
height:50' 'box-sizing:border-box' maxlength='80' name='Last Name' /></td>
    <td style='width:350px; style='height="50px"></td></tr><tr><td  style='word-break: break- 
word;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:Avenir;font:Avenir;width:30%;'><span 
style='color:red;'></span></td>
  <td style='width:40%;' ><input type='text' placeholder="Email Address" 
style='width:200%;height:50''box-sizing:border-box;'  maxlength='100' name='Email' /></td>
    <td style='width:350px; style='height="50px"></td></tr><tr><td  style='word-break: break- 
word;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:Avenir;font:Avenir;width:30%;'><span 
style='color:red;'></span></td>
  <td style='width:40%;' ><input type='text' placeholder="Phone Number" style='width:200%; 
height:50''box-sizing:border-box;'  maxlength='40' name='Phone' /></td>
<td style='width:350px; style='height="50px"></td></tr><tr style='display:none;' ><td 
style='word-break: break-word;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font- 
family:Avenir;font:Avenir;width:30%'>Lead Source</td><td style='width:40%;'>
    <select style='width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;' name='Lead Source'>
    </select></td><td style='width:30%;' ></td></tr><tr style='display:none;' ><td 
 style='word-break: break-word;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:Arial;width:30%'> Introducer </td>
<td style='width:40%;' ><input type='text' style='width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;'  maxlength='255' name='LEADCF1' value='ContractorPeople'></input></td>
    <td style='width:30%;'></td></tr><tr><td  style='word-break: break-word;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:Arial;width:30%;' ></td><td  style='width:40%;'> <textarea name='Description' maxlength='32000' style='width:200%;height:100' >&nbsp;</textarea></td>
<td style='width:30%;'></td></tr>

    <tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align:69%; padding-top:15px;font-size:16px;'>
  <button id="formssubmit">SUBMIT QUERY</button><style type="text/css" type="submit">

#formssubmit { 
 background-color: #ffffff;
 padding: .5em;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 color: #ddddd;
 font-family: 'Avenir';
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border:color:#ffffff;
}

#formssubmit:hover {
 border: none;
 background: #9799A4;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: why is the input width  200% ?

Comment: Im not sure, I have just played with the code to make it work, Im not savy with HTML at all tbh and just trying to get this to work, its for a friend who's left it with me to try and sort!

Comment: try changing the width of all input and the main table width too to 100%, and remove the width from td elements

Comment: Thanks for the Advice Sim, Without sounding 100% inept can you advice which elements specifically to change? I have set quite a few to 350px and 200% so just wondered which ones in particular!

Comment: try using only %, you also have a lot of syntax errors into your HTML, for example `<input type='text' placeholder="Phone Number" style='width:200%; height:50''box-sizing:border-box;'  maxlength='40' name='Phone' />` should be  `<input type='text' placeholder="Phone Number" style='width:200%; height:50px;box-sizing:border-box;'  maxlength='40' name='Phone' />` and the same in  `<td style='width:350px; style='height="50px"></td>` you declare style= twice correct is `<td style='width:350px; height=50px'></td>`

Comment: `<td colspan="3" align="right" style="text-align:69%; padding-top:15px;font-size:16px;" >` - add `align="right"` in `<td>` to align button to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look and there is a lot going on.
I don't see why in each row you have 3 columns. I would remove the first and last as you use your input in the 2nd td but the first and last seem empty:

I would move these table divisions and work with what is left:
`<td style="word-break: break- 
word;text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-family:Avenir;font:Avenir;width:30%;"><span style="color:red;"></span></td>`

`<td style="width:350px; style=" height="50px"></td>`

then you can style the td with your input, you can for example use `padding: 0 20px` or style different `width` so you can position all your inputs the way you want to.

regarding background colors of the input boxes and since you are using inline style you can simply do:

```
<input style="width:200%;height:50; background:#3A3B3F;">
```

regarding the button positioning:
now that you have less table divisions it's also easier to position your button on the right. You can for example add the following css to your formssubmit button:

```
#formssubmit {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

and it will position on the right with a bit of margin.

Does that already help reshape your form a bit closer to what you want it to be?

Comment: Hi Guillaume, thanks for all of that info, Ive managed to sort everything apart from the input box background colours, Ive applied the Background: #3A3B3F; to the stripped out <td Style elements but its not changing colour... is this the correct place to apply that? Thanks!

Comment: @Larryc It's actually in the input style that I added it, like this:`<input style="background:#3A3B3F;">` please let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, Where about in the code line would I insert that component?  <tr>
  <td style="width:350px; style=" height="50px"></td></tr>
  <td style='width:40%;' ><input type='text' placeholder="First Name" style='width:450px; height:50' 'box-sizing:border-box;'  maxlength='80' name='First Name' /></td>

Comment: You do not need to insert. You already have an input there and only need to add what is in bold here.
<tr> <td style="width:350px; style=" height="50px"></td></tr> <td style='width:40%;' ><input type='text' placeholder="First Name" style='width:450px; height:50; **background:#3A3B3F;'** 'box-sizing:border-box;' maxlength='80' name='First Name' /></td>
let me know if it works please.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, thanks for your info its much appreciated, I will upvote and approve the answer, thanks!